# Polymorphic Deserialization function using shapeless

Tags: scala, serialization, shapeless

I'm trying to write a polymorphic deserialization function for hlists/csv's using shapeless

Here is the definition for a Value typeclass that provides serialization/deserialization (I'm aware that the results should probably return and Option/Either/Validation to show failed parsing, but that will come later)

```
class Value[T](val read: String => T, val write: T => String)

object Value {

   implicit object IntValue extends Value[Int](_.toInt, _.toString)

   implicit object StringValue extends Value[String](s => s, s => s)

   def apply[V: Value] = implicitly[Value[V]]
}

import Value._
```

the following serialization function works great

```
object serialize extends Poly1 {
   implicit def caseValue[T: Value] = at[T](Value[T].write)
}
```

and im able to successfully map it over an HList of types that have a supporting Value[_] typeclass:

```
def write[L <: HList, LA1 <: HList](t: L)(
  implicit mapper: Mapper.Aux[writePoly.type, L, LA1],
  lister: ToList[LA1, String]): List[String] = t.map(writePoly).toList
```

Here are the 2 different versions of a  deserialization function ive tried:

```
object deserialize extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseValue[T: Value] = at[String](Value[T].read)
}

object deserialize extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseStr = at[String](Value[String].read)

    implicit def caseInt = at[String](Value[Int].read)
}
```

and I'd like to eventually use it in a function like this

```
def read[L <: HList, LI <: HList](t: LI)(
  implicit mapper: Mapper.Aux[readPoly.type, LI, L]): L = t.map(readPoly)
```

however when i try to map over an HList with the deserialize function, or even when i try to use it on its own like so:

```
deserialize("1")
```

the compiler complains about ambiguous implicit values:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
 both method caseString in object deserialize of type => CsvFormat.deserialize.Case[String]{type Result = String}
 and method caseInt in object deserialize of type => CsvFormat.deserialize.Case[String]{type Result = Int}
 match expected type shapeless.poly.Case[CsvFormat.deserialize.type,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]
    print(deserialize[String]("a"))
                             ^
```

My goal is use this function to map over a list of strings with an HList of Value[_] types in order to serialize them, but since i was getting the same error even while trying to apply the "deserialize" function on a single string, I'm hoping to solve that problem first.

I'm struggling to provide extra type hints to lead the compiler along here, since scala doesnt support type level currying, should i be using something like a type lambda?

Is there any other way I can express this type of function?

Comment: "1" is a  string. at[String] is ambiguous with at[String]. Can you explain what you want to deserialize("1") to do?

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully be more clear, my real goal is to use this in an HList map function, in order to deserialize a list of strings as the required types, using the Value[_].read() typeclass function as the deserializer.

Comment: My guess is that you should map over an `HList` with deserializers and apply those to a `List` of strings. If you map of the list of strings there is no way to tell into which type you want to deserialize them.